# Is there any way in datastage to fetch the isuser(username of the project) to the target table (in user column)

Tags: datastage

I have a suitable job which loads data from source to target, but in addition I want to display the isuser (isuser : which is the username of that respective project) of the Datastage Designer on my target table. It should show the isuser in the user column. Can you help me what steps should I follow.

**Note**
Table headers are as follows

```
+----+------+--------+--------+--------------+
| id | name | f_name | l_name | user(isuser) |
+----+------+--------+--------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can interrogate the DSODB tables JobRun and JobExec to collect this information. The table structures are documented at 
https://docs-ugi.mybluemix.net/docs/content/SSZJPZ_11.7.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ds.monitor.ref.doc/topics/jobruntable.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Transformer stage before the target stage and use Stage Variable in the Transformer. You can set isuser (or dsadm) user as job parameter from job properties, and use this job parameter in the Stage Variables Derivation. Right click on Stage Variables box in Transformer and select Append New Stage Variable. If you click on … and select Job Parameter, it will list all defined job parameter, which then you can select the one set for the username. Afterwards, drag the column to the target table, to that user column in the output link.

Answer (score 0):

The DataStage macro DSProjectName returns the project name of the running job.
Unfortunately there is no macro for the executing user.
You could derive this in an Execute Command activity in the controlling sequence, interrogating appropriate shell variables such as **$USER** or executing a command such as **id** and passing this into your job as a job parameter. Or indeed, you could add the environment variable $USER itself as a job parameter.